# FastCode: studying its code

Tags: delphi

I'm studying the code of FastMM that change the address of the methods and function in run time. But I didn't understand some things.

http://koders.com/delphi/fid356C72C9C454FA74A916971690F624B0FF9111E5.aspx?s=pos

My doubt is on line 47: "if PBYTE(AStub)^ = $E8 then"
Why this comparison? Ok, to check if it's assigned or not. Am I wrong ? But why $E8(232) ?
If it's always the same value, wont it be always the same result ?

The rest of the code it's "ok" in my mind. But if some one could explain all of it I thank.

tks in advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That code returns the target address of a CALL instruction. The test is just to check that it really is a CALL instruction that has been passed to the routine. It's not fool proof because you could be passing the address of the middle of an instruction, or even something that isn't code.

So yes, the test should always succeed, if the function is called correctly.

These two routines are presumably used in tandem. First of all you get the address of the CALL instruction, and then the code at that site is replaced with a JMP ($E9).

Comment: To further clarify, it's looking at the **content** of the first byte in AStub, not the **address** of AStub (note the dereference operator `^`) to see if it's a CALL instruction.

Comment: Hun.... I found http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/call.htm look at call, really the opcode is E8. :D interesting, I have more question, I'll ask soon.

Comment: @SaCi It's exactly as I said. This code is all about replacing one function with another by use of self-modifying code. FastcodeGetAddress works out where the code to be changed is by decoding the relative address next to the CALL ($E8). Then FastcodeAddressPatch finds that code, the target of the CALL and changes it to JMP ($E9) to the new implementation.

Comment: Tks too much for the explanation

Comment: A new point about the code. In this line Result := Pointer(Integer(AStub) + SizeOf(Pointer) + PInteger(AStub)^); I didn't understand why "+ SizeOf(Pointer)". Do you know ?

Comment: it's a relative address, relative to the **end** of the instruction.